# Magento 2 - rewrite checkout and account url

Tags: magento2, php, url-rewrite, administration

What would be the proper way to rewrite/translate Magento 2 checkout and user account URL's to make them localized for my language?

**1. Checkout**

Current checkout URL's are:

`domain.com/checkout`

`domain.com/checkout/#shipping`

`domain.com/checkout/#payment`

**2. User account**

Current user account url's are:

`domain.com/customer`

`domain.com/checkout/account/login`

`domain.com/checkout/account/edit`

`other similar user account URL's...`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by redefining the route. Create a new module that has a module.xml like so...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="[Vendor]_[ModuleName]" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Then in your etc/frontend/routes.xml...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="checkout" frontName="custom-checkout-url">
            <module name="Magento_Checkout" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

I have not looked in to other ways to do it so not sure if it is the *best* way but i have tested it and it worked just fine.

**EDIT**

Because the route has now changed you need to fix up the section reloading when doing ajax. You do this with a "sections.xml" located in etc/frontend that will look something like...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Customer:etc/sections.xsd">
    <action name="custom-checkout-url/cart/add">
        <section name="cart"/>
    </action>
</config>
```

Take a look in the Magento/Catalog/etc/frontend/sections.xml for all the actions you will need to override.

Comment: Great, that works for /checkout. What about #payment and #shipping hash?

Comment: Note: with this solution checkout works but minicart doesn't update.

Comment: So i create another xml (sections.xml) within the same etc/frontend of the module as where the routes.xml is located?

Comment: Never mind, it's working. I'm also updating other url's via this solution (customer, wishilist) and so far so good. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use Magento's URL rewrite feature from your store admin section.

Here are the steps to do so for the domain.com/checkout url:

1. In the admin menu go to Marketing -> URL Rewrites.
2. Click the Add URL rewrite button.
3. Select the "Custom" URL rewrite type
4. Select the store/language for which you want to create the custom url (which will replace domain.com/checkout etc.)
5. In the requested path field enter your new custom url, e.g. new-checkout-url (without leading slahes)
6. In the target path field enter the current/default checkout url: checkout
7. Clear the cache and you're done (maybe also wait for cron to reindex the urls)

The same can be done for any other in-built Magento urls (like domain.com/contact or domain.com/cart).

This is a multi-store and multi-language friendly solution and is better and easier than the accepted answer in my opinion.