# Magento 2 - rewrite contact url

Tags: magento2, contact-us

I change to change default contact url from /contact/ to /customcontact/ or something. How we do that in magento2?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use Magento's URL rewrite feature from your store admin section.

Here are the steps to do so:

1. In the admin menu go to Marketing -> URL Rewrites.
2. Click the Add URL rewrite button.
3. Select the "Custom" URL rewrite type
4. Select the store for which you want to create the custom url (which will replace "contact")
5. In the requested path field type your new custom contact url (e.g. contact-us)
6. In the target path field type the current contact url (contact)
7. Clear the cache and you're done (maybe also wait for cron to reindex the urls)

The same can be done for any other in-built Magento url (like /checkout or /cart).

This is a multi-store and multi-language friendly solution.

Comment: Not working for me. contact.html is giving 404 error. Any solution for this issue? Thank you.

Comment: Not sure... the only alternative is to edit `/vendor/magento/module-contact/etc/frontend/routes.xml` and change **only** the `frontName` attribute from `contact` to whatever you want the url to be. But know that by doing this, you are overriding a core module and when you upgrade Magento, you will lose this change.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this is not the correct solution for this, but I have found alternative way to do it, I have created a page and called contact us block in that page, and SEO url of that page is "contact.html" and my issue is fixed now. This is the correct alternative to it with changing any core file. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar question and answer here [Magento 2 - rewrite checkout and account url](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98956/magento-2-rewrite-checkout-and-account-url)

Just change modify and change it to Contact form module.

Answer (score 0):

If you have applied above solution but if "contact.html" page will give you 404 error, then you can use alternative way to change "contact" url to "contact.html".
I have the same issue, so I have created a Page called "Contact" with "contact.html" url, and I have called contact form block in that page and it is working fine for me.

```
{{block class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" name="contactForm" template="Magento_Contact::form.phtml"}}
```

You have to add above code in Page, and Magento Contact form will work fine.
Thank you.