# How to rewrite Magento 2 default contact page url

Tags: magento2, url, url-rewrite, contact-us

How can I change Magento 2 contacts page URL from /contacts to contact-us.html?

Comment: You can try url rewrite in admin to change this URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to create a CMS page and implement the following block.

```
{block class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" name="contactForm" template="Magento_Contact::form.phtml"}
```

But this would mean /contacts still works, but you could redirect this to the contact-us page.

If you really want to rewrite the url you could follow this method:
[Magento 2 - rewrite checkout and account url](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98956/magento-2-rewrite-checkout-and-account-url)
Wich is actually for checkout URL's but, it'd work the same way for the contacts url.

Answer (score 1):

You can manage via  Url Rewrite. Goto admin>Marketing>Seo & Search> Url rewrite and You need to  2 rewrites .

`contact-us.html` to `contact/index/index` and redirect type NO.Please, select setting like:

[image]

Second: **contact** to `contact-us.html`  and redirect type permanent

[image]