# Contact Page URL Change: Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, url-rewrite, url-key

I have tried to changed the default URL of contact page in magento2 to my custom URL but it is not working at all.

I have tried as follows:

Put the following code in my custom module.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Custom_Module" setup_version="1.0.0">
     <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Contact"/>
    </sequence>
</module>
```

And then rewrite the route as follows in routes.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
   <router id="standard">
       <route id="contact" frontName="kontakt">
           <module name="Magento_Contact" />
       </route>
   </router>
</config>
```

Any Hint what is wrong going on here?

Comment: similar question and answer here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98956/magento-2-rewrite-checkout-and-account-url

Answer (score 0):

You can create url rewrite in Marketing > Url rewrites
Click the Add URL rewrite button.
Select the "Custom" URL rewrite type

Request Path kontact

Target Path contact/index/index

Redirect Type No

Comment: I did that too, still showing the 404 error: http://prntscr.com/mk0gui

Comment: Request Path kontact
Target Path contact/index/index
Redirect Type no

Comment: It will work///