# Magento2 redirect Urls for contact us

Tags: magento2, redirect-url

Magento2 how can I redirect following contact URL to another

```
contact-us/?id=104972   >> contact/
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create a CMS page and implement the following block.

```
{block class=""Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm"" name=""contactForm"" template=""Magento_Contact::form.phtml""}
```

But this would mean /contacts still works, but you could redirect this to the contact-us page.

If you really want to rewrite the URL you could follow this method: [Magento 2 - rewrite checkout and account url](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98956/magento-2-rewrite-checkout-and-account-url)
Which is actually for checkout URL's but it'd work the same way for the contacts URL.